# vue.js unexpected string ...Component.options)' + '}

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm very new in vue.js. In my localhost, it works fine, But when i upload to host, it gives me the error  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` in `w4.js?v=2:115` w4.js is app.js, i change it from webpack.mix.js.

And it's `w4.js` line 115

```
if(!module.hot.data){
hotAPI.createRecord("data-v-0ffd8218",Component.options)
}else{
hotAPI.reload("data-v-0ffd8218",Component.options)' + '
}
```

So, i remove all `' + '` code on line error. And my problem is solved. But i still don't know why my code didn't work fine in localhost?

When i change some parts in vue, it will generate new `w4.js`and i should remove that error line again.

it's my `app.js`

```
import swal from 'sweetalert'
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('groups', require('./components/Groups.vue'));
Vue.component('group', require('./components/Group.vue'));
Vue.component('test', require('./components/Test.vue'));
Vue.component('pages', require('./components/Pages.vue'));
Vue.component('page', require('./components/Page.vue'));

const groups = new Vue({
    el: '#groups',
});


const pages = new Vue({
    el: '#pages',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into how to run HMR(hot module reload) on a server?

https://github.com/webpack/docs/issues/45

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why i should run HMR on server? Can i just build on local and upload to server?